# How do I find expectation value of $1/r$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, orbitals

I know that the expectation value of $x$ is $\left\langle \psi \middle| x \middle| \psi \right\rangle=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \psi(x)^2x \,dx$. But what if I need to calculate $\frac{1}{r}$? Do I need to integrate over $dr$ or over the volume element in spherical coordinates?

Answer (score 3):

Yes! If you are finding $\langle 1/r\rangle$ then it's rather obvious that you are dealing with wave function in $3D$ that is of the form $\psi(r,\theta,\phi)$.
$$\left\langle \frac{1}{r}\right\rangle=\int_V \frac{1}{r}\ |\psi(r,\theta,\phi)|^2dV=\int_V \frac{1}{r}\ |\psi(r,\theta,\phi)|^2 r^2\sin\theta\  dr \ d\theta \ d\phi $$

Comment: Perfect! And the volume should be the one I am working on, right?

Comment: Yeah, See the range of wavefunction.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, to obtain expectation value of physical quantities $\langle \psi|A(\hat{X},\hat{P})|\psi \rangle$

$1.$ You need to specify the Hamiltonian of the system

$2.$ Explore the symmetry of the system to choose a convenient coordinate

$3.$ Solve the Schrodinger equation to obtain the wave function

$4.$ Solve the integral in the chosen coordinate basis

As Young Kindaichi answer implicitly stated, you actually inserted the identity operator $\hat{I}=\int |r,\theta,\phi\rangle \langle r,\theta,\phi|  d^3{r}$, in spherical coordinate the volume element then automatically gives $d^3r=r^2\sin\theta drd\theta d\phi$

Explicitly the calculation is given by: $\langle \psi|\hat{A}(\hat{X},\hat{P})|\psi \rangle=\langle \psi|\hat{A}(\hat{X},\hat{P})\hat{I}|\psi \rangle $

=$\int \langle \psi|r,\theta,\phi\rangle \hat{A} \langle r,\theta,\phi |\psi \rangle r^2\sin\theta drd\theta d\phi $

=$\int \psi(r,\theta,\phi)A(x,p)\psi(r,\theta,\phi) r^2\sin\theta dr d\theta d\phi$